# Harvard University CS50 Lecture on Flask

Tags: flask, pycharm

I am taking CS50 lecture on Python Flask
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVA0fD13NGI&t=5449s
I am using PyCharm instead of VS Code. Here is my problem.
When I make changes in my PyCharm code and "Save All"  I should be able to just "refresh" my browser to see the changes, (That's what the CS50 instructor can do), but I have to Stop and Start my Flask server and then go back to my browser in order to see the change.
Is there something I need to turn on and/or configure in PyCharm so that when I make code changes in a Flask application I can just refresh the browser without having to Stop/Start the Flask server.  Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.

Comment: Please read [flask-development-server](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/server/).

Answer (score 0):

if you running your application with `flask run` in terminal, you can use `--debug` before `run`, to run in watch mode like this `flask --debug run`.

Have another away to run in watch mode.

You can use this code in your main file

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
  app.run(debug=True)
```

when you run, you have to use python like this `python app.py`.

You can see more in the flask documents [Here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/debugging/)